# HttpClient request to local IIS 8.0 does not produce expected headers in the response

Tags: http, http-headers, .net-4.5, iis-8

I'm making the following request to a local website running in IIS

```
var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
httpRequestMessage.RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost:8081/");
httpRequestMessage.Method = HttpMethod.Get;

var response = new HttpClient().SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
```

This produces the following response headers:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes
>   Date: Mon, 03 Jun 2013 22:34:25 GMT
>   ETag: "50c7472eb342ce1:0"
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

An identical request made via Fiddler produces the following response headers (I've highlighted the differences):

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   **Content-Type: text/html**
>   **Last-Modified: Fri, 26 Apr 2013 19:20:58 GMT**
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes
>   ETag: "50c7472eb342ce1:0"
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   Date: Mon, 03 Jun 2013 22:29:34 GMT
>   **Content-Length: 10**

Why is there a difference in response headers?
Am I using HttpClient correctly (aside from the fact I am calling Send synchronously)?

Comment: Have you verified the requests are actually identical? Could you post both requests here too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

To access **all** response headers you need to read both `HttpResponseMessage.Headers` and `HttpResponseMessage.Content.Headers` properties.

**Long(er) answer:**

This, basically:

```
var response = new HttpClient().GetAsync("http://uri/").Result;
var allHeaders = response.Headers.Union(response.Content.Headers);

foreach (var header in allHeaders)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

I see two issues with this:

- The `Headers` property is not appropriately named: it should really be `SomeHeaders` or `AllHeadersExceptContentHeaders`. (I mean, really, when you see a property named `Headers`, do you expect it to return *all* headers or *some* headers? I am pretty sure they are in violation of their own framework design guidelines on this one.)
- The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.headers.aspx) does not mention at any point the fact this is **a subset of all headers** and developers should also inspect `Content.Headers`.